# React does not rendar child component data when looping an array sent as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm new to React and trying to pass an array of object to a child component. But the child component renders nothing. Below is my code

```
This is my array in home.js

board: [
  {
    name: 'todo',
    tasks: [
      {
        description: '',
        name: 'first task',
        id: uuid(),
        userAssigned: null
      },
      {
        description: '',
        name: 'second task',
        id: uuid(),
        userAssigned: null
      },
      {
        description: '',
        name: 'and thrid',
        id: uuid(),
        userAssigned: null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'in-progress',
    tasks: [
      {
        description: '',
        name: 'first task',
        id: uuid(),
        userAssigned: null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'done',
    tasks: [
      {
        description: '',
        name: 'first task',
        id: uuid(),
        userAssigned: null
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

and this is how I render the array

```
<Row>
  {
    this.state.board.map(cname => (
      <Col key={cname.name} md="2">
        <Card border="dark">
          <Card.Title className="text-center py-2 mb-0">{cname.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            <Task tasks={cname.tasks} />
          </Card.Text>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    ))
  }
</Row>
```

So here `Task` is an child component it is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';


class TaskCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <template>
        {
          this.props.tasks.map(element => {
            <Card border="dark">
              <Card.Text>{element.name}</Card.Text>
            </Card>
          })
        }
      </template >

    );
  }
}

export default TaskCard
```

Now in the above code of child component it does not display name of the task as stated in the array. I need to display the task-> name in card text.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return` statement inside the map function. That's why the Card is not shown.

```
{
    this.props.tasks.map(element => {
        return (
            <Card border="dark">
                <Card.Text>{element.name}</Card.Text>
            </Card>
       )
    })
}
```

You could also do it the same way you have done it for the mapping of the board array:

```
{
    this.props.tasks.map(element => (
        <Card border="dark">
            <Card.Text>{element.name}</Card.Text>
        </Card>
    ))
}
```

Comment: It gives an error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {description, name, id, userAssigned}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: The error shouldn't occur since you only display `element.name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
return (
  <template>
    {
      this.props.tasks.map(element => (
        <Card border="dark">
          <Card.Text>{element.name}</Card.Text>
        </Card>
      ))
    }
  </template >
);
```

}

use parenthesis for rendering the JSX Content inside map loop instead of curly braces.

Following code is running on my side.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(true);
  const board = [
   {
    name: "todo",
     tasks: [
     {
      description: "",
      name: "first task",
      id: 12,
      userAssigned: null
    },
    {
      description: "",
      name: "second task",
      id: 23,
      userAssigned: null
    },
    {
      description: "",
      name: "and thrid",
      id: 34,
      userAssigned: null
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "in-progress",
  tasks: [
    {
      description: "",
      name: "first task",
      id: 45,
      userAssigned: null
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "done",
  tasks: [
    {
      description: "",
      name: "first task",
      id: 56,
      userAssigned: null
    }
   ]
  }
 ];

return (
  <div className="App">
     <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

     {board.map((element) => (
       <Task tasks={element.tasks} key={element.id} />
     ))}
  </div>
 );
}

function Task({ tasks }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((e) => (
        <h3 key={e.id}>{e.name}</h3>
      ))}
    </div>
   );
}
```